# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_chdir at process.chdir when creating a directory and changing into it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to write a small app that installs some files and modules in a new folder, but I keep getting this error:

{ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_chdir
    at process.chdir (/home/aboardwithabag/LaunchProject/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:20:9)
    at cd (/home/aboardwithabag/LaunchProject/index.js:26:13)

Below is my code.  Can someone help me out?

```
// node LaunchProject projectName
// Installs a server, node modules, and index page.
// not working due to issues with chdir.

const cp = require('child_process');
const fse = require('fs-extra');
// const path = require('path');
const project = process.argv[2];

let server ="";
let home = "";

function make (cb){
  fse.mkdirs(project, function(err){
    if (err){
      console.error(err);
    }
  });
  cb;
}

function cd(cb){
  try{
    process.chdir('/'+project);
    cb;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }}

function install(cb){
  cp.exec('npm install express', function(err){
    if (err){
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Express Installed.');
      cp.exec('npm install ejs', function(err){
        if (err){
          console.error(err);
        } else{
          console.log('Ejs Installed.');
          fse.outputFile('index.js', server);
          fse.outputFile('public/index.html', home);
      }});
    }
  });
  cb;
}


make(cd(install(console.log(project + ' created.'))));
```

Answer (score 0):

unless the folder name you assign to the project variable (in this case it seems to be "uv_chdir") is located at the root folder of your HDD, below line will give the error:

```
process.chdir('/'+project);
```

make sure you give correct path to the program arguments. (in this case argv[2])

Or you may remove the leading '/' and make the path relative.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are some issues with this code.

1. `cb` callbacks provided as function arguments need to be called not after the async calls, but inside the callbacks of these calls. For example:

```js
function make (cb){
  fse.mkdirs(project, function(err){
    if (err){
      console.error(err);
    }
    cb();
  });
}
```

2. The last call chain `make(cd(install(console.log(project + ' created.'))));` would work only with sync calls in reversed order and only if they returned needed callbacks.

   That is why your new dir is not ready when you try to use it: your async functions do not actually wait for each other.
3. You do not call your callbacks as `cb()`, just mention them as `cb`. You should call them.

With minimal changess, your code can be refactored in this way:

```js
'use strict';

const cp = require('child_process');
const fse = require('fs-extra');
const project = process.argv[2];

let server = '';
let home = '';

make(cd, install, () => { console.log(project + ' created.'); });

function make(cb1, cb2, cb3) {
  fse.mkdirs(project, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    cb1(cb2, cb3);
  });
}

function cd(cb1, cb2) {
  try {
    process.chdir('/' + project);
    cb1(cb2);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

function install(cb1) {
  cp.exec('npm install express', (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Express Installed.');
      cp.exec('npm install ejs', (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          console.log('Ejs Installed.');
          fse.outputFile('index.js', server);
          fse.outputFile('public/index.html', home);
          cb1();
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

But it is rather brittle and unnecessarily complicated in this form. Maybe it would be simpler to inline your functions each in other.

Answer (score -1):

when I use PM2,i got this error "no such file or directory, uv_chdir"
the resolvent is :
first,I use 'pm2 delete' to delete old process
second,I use 'pm2 start',then ok

ps : just change your code or use 'pm2 reload' or 'pm2 restart' would not be ok.

more detail , you can see "https://blog.csdn.net/u013934914/article/details/51145134"